# Why am I not gaining reputation for upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki

(Apologies if this is the wrong forum/format, I am open to guidance.)

I posted a question yesterday (*[What is your favorite statistical graph?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109076/what-is-your-favorite-statistical-graph)*), modeled along the lines of another well received question on CV. My question and the initial answers have been well received. As of a few hours ago, and of this writing, the question received 8 up votes (7 yesterday, 1 today) and scads of views. However, I received reputation for only 4 of these up votes, despite being well below the 200 reputation daily limit (*curse you [Mortarboard badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard)!*), and not receiving any down votes or (as far as I can tell) any flags.

My questions:

1. Is this a case of missing reputation, or a case of my not understanding how reputation works? Enlightenment welcome.
2. Was there some sort of flag, or something I am missing that would indicate that I *have* overstepped a CV/SE boundary somewhere?

Comment: I struggled to decide whether to close the question outright or convert it to CW. Strictly speaking such questions are off topic on SE.  This one was asked in a way that encouraged productive and useful answers; IMHO it's not merely a "fun" thread, but nevertheless it's one that clearly has no right or best answer.  The purpose of CW status is to allow such threads to fit appropriately within the question-answer-vote-accept-gain reputation framework.  You should be pleased to have gained any  reputation at all for the four upvotes made before CW status was applied :-).

Comment: Additionally to what whuber said, there will be lots of badges for you to compensate your idea :)

Comment: And badges for us answerers too :D Don't sweat the mortarboard one; with your rate and quality of contributions, you'll get it soon enough (probably just a matter of waiting for one of your answers to land on a "Hot Network Question" when you also happen to be having a fairly successful day otherwise). Thanks for asking, and thanks to the community for keeping it as a wiki! It's tough to see when one of these big list questions is going to be a good fit for the community, but I saw a lot of upvotes on your question before I saw the first close vote, which I think is a good sentiment indicator.

Comment: BTW, regarding big list questions, see also [What could be done with respect to tag “big-list”?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1846/32036)

Comment: I expect you'll hit the Mortarboard badge soon enough. If you count my active period here from mid-September 2012 (I was on for a good while before then but only intermittently answering), it was just over six months before I hit 200 the first time. There's no great secret to it, though it helps to have several days with a few good contributions in a row (because a good post will get votes over several days, and accepts may take some days as well). Sooner or later one of those good contributions will get not 4 or 5 votes but a dozen or so, and then a couple of other good answers will do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You (or possibly a moderator) seem to have checked the "[community wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)" box when editing the question.

The result being, that the post has become a community wiki post, which means there are no reputation gains for the OP.

You can edit to remove the checkbox, but any upvotes that occurred during the period it was community wiki will not count towards your reputation.

Comment: From the [revision history](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/109076/revisions) it appears the moderator whuber made the change to make it community wiki. In my experience this is common on Cross-Validated for "fun" questions that ask for a list of favorites [like this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-is-your-favorite-data-analysis-cartoon) or [or this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/statistics-jokes)

Comment: @DavidRobinson - should have looked in the revisions... I looked elsewhere, which didn't have that bit of data.

Comment: Looks like the link to the revision history isn't active when the only revision is making community-wiki. Feature request?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - because nothing changed in the question text/title/tags.

Comment: I know, I meant that that makes it hard to reach the page and find out that it was made a wiki.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - yep true enough :)